# Does GIL affect parallel processing of a python script in separate terminal windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, parallel-processing, gil

I am trying to understand Python's GIL. I recently had an assignment where I had to compare the execution times of a certain task performed using different algorithms of different time complexities on multiple input files. I ran a python script to do the same, but I used separate terminal windows on macOS to run the same python script for different input files.

I also ran it all in one terminal window, one after the other, for each input file. The CPU time for this was lower for each execution as compared to the previous approach with multiple windows where each program took twice as long but ran all at once. (Note : there were 4 terminal windows in the previous approach and the python script only ran an a.out executable compiled with clang on macOS and stored the output in different files).

Can anyone explain why running them in parallel lead to each program being slower? Did they run on separate cores or did the GIL lead to each program being slower than it would if I run it one at a time in one terminal window?

Comment: Does the program access disk or something else shared?

Comment: The program takes an input of numbers from stdin and prints 3 strings to stdout both of which I redirected to files using the < and > followed by different file names for each program. I don't think they share anything since the a.out is just a sorting program with 1 function other than the main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each terminal window will start a new python interpreter, each of which has its own GIL.  The difference is probably due to contention for some resource at the OS level (disk i/o, memory, cpu cycles).

Comment: Each script runs a.out using popen() and redirects the output to a different text file. So it's not the GIL and I don't see what else they share. Maybe CPU cycles.

Comment: If you have a multi-core cpu and magnetic disk, it's probably I/O contention, but yes, it's certainly something other than the GIL